# Tomcat GlobalNamingResources ResourceLink Oracle get DataSource

Tags: oracle, tomcat, jdbc

I'm having difficulty getting a JDBC DataSource using Tomcat 7

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/weblogin01b] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:818)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:166)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceLinkFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceLinkFactory.java:92)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:841)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:152)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:829)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:166)
```

In CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml

I have included a variety of slightly different resources 
all aiming to be the same connection hopefully one of them will be right:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />


    <Resource name="jdbc/weblogin01"
        username="weblogin01"
        password="xxxxx"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
        description="Global Address Database"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.15.120.29:1522:DGSPC"
        maxActive="15"
        maxIdle="3" />

    <Resource name="jdbc/weblogin01b"
        user="weblogin01"
        password="xxxxx"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.15.120.29:1522:DGSPC"
        maxActive="20"
        maxIdle="3"
        maxWait="-1" />   

    <Resource name="jdbc/weblogin01c"
        user="weblogin01"
        password="xxxxx"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.15.120.29:1522:DGSPC"
        maxActive="20"
        maxIdle="3"
        maxWait="-1" />   

</GlobalNamingResources>
```

In META-INF/context.xml

I have a ResourceLink to each resource

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/testDbAccess">
    <ResourceLink name="jdbc/weblogin01"
        global="jdbc/weblogin01"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
    <ResourceLink name="jdbc/weblogin01b"
        global="jdbc/weblogin01b"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
    <ResourceLink name="jdbc/weblogin01c"
        global="jdbc/weblogin01c"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

In web.xml I made no changes related to JDBC on the understanding that
the ResourceLink elements will be sufficient.

In Java code I try to get a DataSource as follows:

```
String dbUser = "weblogin01b";
try {
    // Obtain our environment naming context
    Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
    Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");

    // Look up our data source
    ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/" + dbUser);          
    if (ds == null) {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING,"Null datasource for " + dbUser);
    }
}
```

Given the exception above, it never gets a DataSource, this is the same for:
jdbc/weblogin01
jdbc/weblogin01b
jdbc/weblogin01c

I'm finding Tomcat an uphill struggle, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 2 of the puzzle is solved:

That should be:

```
username="weblogin01"
```

NOT

```
user="weblogin01"
```

Answer (score 2):

Part 1 of the puzzle is solved:

I was editing the wrong copy of server.xml

I am running Tomcat under NetBeans which makes a separate copy of CATALINA_HOME which it configures as CATALINA_BASE, I had not noticed the separate copy.

I wish Tomcat's CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE were always separate and distinctly different, i.e. no duplication of files.

Part 2 is a different story:
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

I know that I've specified the correct username and password but I'm not seeing these values logged anywhere, I'm guessing that I've specified the correct values in the wrong properties.